# Criando um loop com php e mySQL

Tags: php, sql, loop, auto-incremento

Preciso de uma ajuda para criar uma função em *PHP*.

- Tenho uma tabela no banco em *MySQL*, onde em uma coluna quero variar a numeração de 1 a 4 por registro.
- Para isso tenho um formulário onde o cliente preenche e automaticamente define um auto incremento.
- Ou seja:

Usuário A registrou, automaticamente define um id 001
Usuário B registrou, automaticamente define um id 002
Usuário C registrou, automaticamente define um id 003
Usuário D registrou, automaticamente define um id 004
Usuário E registrou, automaticamente volta a definir o id 001

e assim por diante.

Alguém pode me ajudar a criar isso?

Comment: no caso não poderia ser um id o id (chave primaria não pode se repetir) o que você poderia fazer é acionar uma segunda coluna chamado `id_secundario` e trabalhar do 1 até 4.

Comment: Sim é exatamente isso, mas esses id é referente ao usuário do sistema, quero atribuir nesta tabela um registro para cada usuário ter acesso. Por esse motivo quero o loop nos "id_secundario", pois recebemos uma quantidade enorme de cadastro e apenas um usuário tem acesso a esse registro, quero balancear os registros por usuários.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode trabalhar com as [Functions](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_ref_mysql.asp) do MySQL para te ajudar, no momento do insert basta você chamar uma função programada que ela já vai te informar qual o próximo id que você pode utilizar. Lembro que se o id for a chave primária o seu objetivo não vai poder ser atendido.

> **NOTA:** Recomendo que você crie a função apenas no momento da instalação.

Deixo abaixo um exemplo de uma tabela criada para expor a funcionalidade.

```
-- Entidade criada para testes
CREATE TABLE teste_incremento (
  id int primary key auto_increment,
  id_secundario int,
  nome varchar(200)
);

-- Crio uma função para retornar o próximo id secundário
CREATE FUNCTION RecuperaProximoIdSecundario ()
RETURNS INT RETURN (
  CASE
    WHEN (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM teste_incremento) = 0 THEN 1
    WHEN (SELECT id_secundario FROM teste_incremento ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1) = 4 THEN 1
    ELSE (SELECT id_secundario FROM teste_incremento ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1) + 1
 END
);
```

Abaixo deixo o cenário para teste, a definição da função precisa ser feito apenas na criação do banco de dados.

```
-- Testes para fazer a inserção
INSERT INTO teste_incremento (id_secundario, nome)
VALUES (RecuperaProximoIdSecundario(), "Hiago");

INSERT INTO teste_incremento (id_secundario, nome)
VALUES ( RecuperaProximoIdSecundario(), "Fernando");

INSERT INTO teste_incremento (id_secundario, nome)
VALUES ( RecuperaProximoIdSecundario(), "João");

INSERT INTO teste_incremento (id_secundario, nome)
VALUES ( RecuperaProximoIdSecundario(), "Maria");

INSERT INTO teste_incremento (id_secundario, nome)
VALUES ( RecuperaProximoIdSecundario(), "Reinaldo");

INSERT INTO teste_incremento (id_secundario, nome)
VALUES ( RecuperaProximoIdSecundario(), "Marcos");

INSERT INTO teste_incremento (id_secundario, nome)
VALUES ( RecuperaProximoIdSecundario(), "Joana");

-- Select para ver o resultado para fazer a inserção
SELECT * FROM teste_incremento;
```

Você pode ver o exemplo acima funcionando no [DBFiddler](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gAjjfd51NGZg3q2rUV1nA4/0) que eu disponibilizei.

Espero que tenha ajudado.

Comment: Opa, funcionou certinho! Vlw irmão :D